# Sqlite Integer null == java int 0

Tags: java, sqlite

I guess that an integer null value within a sqlite table is not equivalent to 0 in Java. So how can I check whether the int I extract from my table with

```
   if(resultSet.getInt(columnNumber) != 0){
      System.out.println("int is not null");
   }
```

is not null? I do not want to use the sqlite constraint "IS NOT NULL".

Comment: An easy way to figure this out is to debug your program and see what `resultSet.getInt(columnNumber)` returns when the value is null

Comment: You can use `resultSet.getObject`

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends what this method is doing: `resultSet.getInt(...)`

if getInt is returning a primitive integer, then that can not be null, but if that is an object of the class Integer then you need to check the nullabilty by doing a normal check like: `resultSet.getInt(...)!= null` and then after been sure that is ot null check if is not zero:

```
resultSet.getInt(...)!=0
```

## Example:

```
if(resultSet.getInt(columnNumber) != null){
    if(resultSet.getInt(columnNumber) != 0){
        System.out.println("int is not zero");
    } else {
        System.out.println("int is zero");
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("int is null");
}
```

Comment: There is a common [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) interface and it is very unlikely that his implementation doesn't implements that, so `getInt` returns `int`.